# Read Parquet files without reading into memory (using Python) from URL

Tags: python, download, stream, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to read NY data set which is stored & publically available [here](https://www.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page), I extracted the underlying location of the parquet file for the 2022 as "https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2019-01.parquet". Now I was trying to read data form this URL and used the `read_parquet` method to do it quite easily. But I am not able to figure out on how to read this data if the data size is too big and which might cause memory overload. Unlike `read_csv` does not have stream option & converting into `pyarrow.parquet.parquetfile` to use its iter_batches functionality does not seem to be an option since it cannot read from URL

Answer (score 0):

You could use the filter option to load only part of the file based on timestamps:

```
pd.read_parquet(
'https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2019-01.parquet', 
filters=[
('tpep_pickup_datetime','>=',pd.Timestamp('2019-1-1T10:00')),
 ('tpep_pickup_datetime','<',pd.Timestamp('2019-1-1T11:00'))
])
```

However, since its https, it will probably need to download the full file anytime you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really read directly from the url, but this implementation isn't that complex and won't run you out of memory. That seems to help:

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

base_url = 'https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/green_tripdata_2022-01.parquet'
os.system(f"curl -O {base_url}")
path = urlparse(base_url).path
parquet_file_path = f"./{os.path.basename(path)}"
parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(parquet_file_path)
```

And from there you can use `iter_batches` and the other options on the `parquet_file` object. Full code here: https://github.com/arthurfg/data-engineering-course/blob/main/week_1_basics_n_setup/docker_sql/parquet_to_postgres.py